# SQLDeveloper displays no tables under connections where it says tables

Tags: oracle, oracle-sqldeveloper

I am not sure why but I just installed SQLdeveloper 32 bit (3.0.0.4).  When I click to expand the tables/views/indexes or etc it displays nothing at all!

But when I do the following:

```
SELECT owner, table_name   
FROM dba_tables
```

I see the list of tables and I have read access to these tables since I can do a select * from anytable and data shows. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 56, accepted):

The SQL Developer tree shows you what objects you own, not what objects you have access to.  If you want to see the objects that you have access to that are owned by other users, you would need to navigate to the "Other Users" branch of the tree, then the user that owns the table, then the "Tables" branch.

Comment: This is someting new in my dictionary. I checked other uses. In that tree, there is large list of database schemas. Now How can I come to know that, which schema is used by me sql query ?? Any suggestion ??

Comment: @GunjanShah - Sorry, I'm not sure that I understand the question.  And it sounds like it might be a separate question, not a comment on this answer.  If you're running a query and that your identifiers are not fully qualified, those identifiers would be resolved first against objects in the current schema then against public synonyms.  You can query `all_objects` to see see what objects have a particular name and work out from there which object is being used.

Comment: How do you find the other users branch?

Comment: @java123999 - At least in the current version, it's the last branch of the tree below "XML DB Repository", "Scheduler", and "Recycle Bin"

Answer (score 1):

Add select privilege to all_objects/user/ojects in the db user

Answer (score 0):

For me also same problem happened, the tree structure under hr schema like Tables, Views, Indexes, Packages etc was not there, I deleted the sql developer folder and downloaded freshly and extracted, now I got the tree structure back.Try it.

Answer (score -1):

Launch SQL Developer as administrator