# SQl Table displays no table under connection

Tags: oracle-sqldeveloper

I am using Orable DB in my application and SQL Developer Query Browser for UI Purpose.

Today I faced a very strage issue, I run a query in the query browser which gives me records successfully. But under the connection -> Table tree hierarchy, no tables are displayed.

From stackoverflow I got a solution from here : [SQLDeveloper displays no tables under connections where it says tables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6459145/sqldeveloper-displays-no-tables-under-connections-where-it-says-tables/6459242#6459242)

But under "Other Users" tree, it displays large list of schemas. So I am confused which schema is used by me query.

Any suggestion ??

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you are running a query that involves an unqualified identifier

```
SELECT *
  FROM some_object
```

and that you haven't done something odd like changing the `current_schema` of the session, the object is either something that exists in your schema or is a public synonym.

```
SELECT owner, object_type, object_name
  FROM all_objects
 WHERE object_name = 'SOME_OBJECT'
```

will show you all the objects that you have access to with that name.

Comment: Hi, I first tried with this query : SELECT owner,object_type, object_name FROM all_objects; It gave me a large list of recrods. Then I tried to find out the owner details of the schema that I am using. My schema name is "TRP_DB". So i fired query : SELECT owner,object_type, object_name
  FROM  all_objects
  WHERE object_name like '%TRP%'; But it gives empty resultset. So does it mean that I dont have access to "TRP_DB" schema ???

Comment: @GunjanShah - If `TRP_DB` is the name of the schema, that would be in the `owner` column, not the `object_name` column.  `object_name` would be the name of the table, view, materialized view, synonym, public synonym, or other object that you're actually querying.  What is the name of the object that you are querying?  That's the `object_name` that you want to search for.

Comment: Thanks for quich response. Ok.. I searched on owner name='TRP_DB'. And I got the result like : Owner -> TRP_DB, OBJECT_TYPE -> TABLE, OBJECT_NAME -> SQLN_EXPLAIN_PLAN.  But, Justin I want to know the reason why the list of table is empty in TABLE tree. And How it becomes possible here to fetch the records even though no tables are displayed in the tree. Can you please explain in detail ?

Comment: @GunjanShah - Because, as `all_objects` confirms, your user doesn't own any tables.  As I've said, search for the object name, not the schema owner.  My guess is that there is a public synonym that you're querying.